# Не выводит данные из базы данных в JSON

Tags: php, sql, json

Всем хорошего здоровьица!

Начинаю только нормально изучать php и заинтересовался передачей данных через JSON. Но вот у меня такая проблема: у меня есть файл, содержащий следующую информацию

`{"success":true,"data":{"name":"Илона","surname":"Маска","email":"example@gmail.com","avatar":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/files\/avatars\/photo.jpg"}}`

По сути все работает как должно когда код выглядит именно так, но беда в том что когда данные вывожу из базы данных, то в самом файле они тоже без всяких проблем отображаются, а когда вывожу информацию на другом сайте то сайт ее не читает, и это исключительно информация из базы данных.

В чем может быть проблема, и как ее решить?

Comment: В каком смысле `не читает`? Какие-то ошибки выдаёт?

Comment: Никаких ошибок нет. Я создал файл где ````{"success":true,"data":{"name":"Илона","surname":"Маска","email":"example@gmail.com","avatar":"https:\/\/www.example.com\/files\/avatars\/photo.jpg"}}```
Когда перехожу по ссылке так и все пишет, а когда подключаю через API на другой сайт, вывожу значения , то те значения что выводились с бд сайт не читает

Comment: Надо бы поподробнее расписать, так не понятно. Как выводите данные, в файле они всё-таки хранятся, или в БД, что за API, которым связываете сайты?